# SQL based on Timestamp Difference calculation ON Multi table with multi condition - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

*Table structure and sample data*

### Wall_Update

```
   [INT         VARCHAR       VARCHAR         TIMESTAMP               TinyText]   
   pid [pk] |  CreatedBy  |   RepliedBy   |     Time               |     Text    

   1        |   sourav    |     sachin    |   2011-04-09 21:26:01  |      Hi
```

### Friends

```
  UID  |    fUID

sourav |   sachin  
sachin |   sourav
```

I need to get PID for all those posts which was created by SOURAV or a friend of SOURAV and the Timeshould be atmost 3days old !

So i tried this 2 queries [and both fails]

```
select pid,`Text`,CreatedBy,Time,RepliedBy from WALL_UPDATE where CreatedBy in 
  (select FUID from friends where UID='sourav') or CreatedBy='sourav' and 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF (DAY , Time,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<=3 order by PID desc

SELECT WU.pid,WU.Text,MN.NameF,WU.Time,WU.CreatedBy FROM wall_update WU,main MN WHERE
  WU.CreatedBy in (select FUID from FRIENDS where UID='sourav') or
  WU.CreatedBy='sourav' and MN.uid=WU.createdBy and 
     TIMESTAMPDIFF (DAY , WU.time,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) <3 group by WU.pid
```

[both returns all PID created by SOURAV or a friend of SOURAV]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

> select * from WALL_UPDATE    where
>   (`CreatedBy` IN (select fuid from
>   FRIENDS where uid ='sourav') 
>           or CreatedBy='sourav') 
>           and TIMESTAMPDIFF (DAY ,`Time`,now()) <=3
>           order by pid desc

use primary id to refer a friend user not name ,This will create dublicate

Comment: ERROR-> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Thats y i said use primary key to refer friend and user id ...check your db how much sourav exists...i ll update with results

Comment: UID, fUID both these keys are primary in Friends table

Comment: then there is no possible for multiple records in sub query

Comment: @Gowri i want to get the result you have shown in the RESULT OF QUERY, how to get it ? i mean what part you modified in the table or any ?

Comment: now check my edit bro! i am wrongly used = for IN ..let me know is that helps